# Can't index certain classes from an html file with python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an html file that follows the following format where a each row consists of a `player`, `team`, `position`, `exposure_x`, and `exposure_y`:

```
<p class="p1">
    &lt;div style="height: 15840px; width: 369px;"&gt;&lt;div role="row" class="BaseTable__row PlayerExposureTable_dk-grid-row PlayerExposureTable_row-odd" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 369px; height:
    60px;"&gt;&lt;div role="gridcell" class="BaseTable__row-cell DKResponsiveGrid_dk-grid-column undefined" style="flex: 0 1 auto; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;"&gt;&lt;div class="PlayerNameCell_player-name-cell" aria-label="Hunter
    Henry"&gt;&lt;img class="PlayerNameCell_player-icon" src="https://dkn.gs/sports/images/nfl/players/160/19156.png" alt="Hunter Henry"&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;div class="PlayerNameCell_name-and-status"&gt;&lt;img
    class="PlayerNameCell_team-icon" src="https://dkn.gs/sports/images/nfl/teams/logos/160/18415.png" alt="NE team icon"&gt;&lt;div class="PlayerNameCell_player-name"&gt;H. Henry&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div
    class="PlayerNameCell_status"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div
    class="PlayerNameCell_position-and-team"&gt;&lt;div&gt;TE&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;·&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;NE&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div role="gridcell" class="BaseTable__row-cell
    DKResponsiveGrid_dk-grid-column undefined" style="flex: 0 1 auto; width: 90px; overflow: hidden;"&gt;&lt;div class="PlayerExposureTable_detail-cell"&gt;250&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div role="gridcell" class="BaseTable__row-cell
    DKResponsiveGrid_dk-grid-column undefined" style="flex: 0 1 auto; width: 85px; overflow: hidden;"&gt;&lt;div class="PlayerExposureTable_detail-cell"&gt;35%&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div role="row" class="BaseTable__row
    PlayerExposureTable_dk-grid-row " style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 60px; width: 369px; height: 60px;"&gt;&lt;div role="gridcell" class="BaseTable__row-cell DKResponsiveGrid_dk-grid-column undefined" style="flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 200px; overflow: hidden;"&gt;&lt;div class="PlayerNameCell_player-name-cell" aria-label="Jakobi Meyers"&gt;&lt;img class="PlayerNameCell_player-icon" src="https://dkn.gs/sports/images/nfl/players/160/17948.png" alt="Jakobi
    Meyers"
    ...
</p>
```

Where my desired output is

```
Hunter Henry, NE, TE, 250, 35%
Jakobi Meyers, ...
...
```

Normally, I would go about this by indexing html classes via bs4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('my_file.html') as f:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html")
```

And then using `zip()` to combine lists of the values from each class, or something similar.

But I can't seem to get it to work:

```
soup.find_all('div', {"class_":"PlayerNameCell_player-name-cell"})
>>> []

[value for element in soup.find_all(class_=True) for value in element["class"]]
>>> ['p1']
```

As I cannot find my desired class(es) (the only class seems to be just `p1`).

So my question is, how come this html is tricky to index? Usually, I have no problems with doing stuff like this.

Comment: That html example you provided is like looking at perlin noise and trying to find an individual dot. Is it really necessary to leave it as cumbersome as possible? Help us help you. Honestly, if you cleaned it up you could probably answer your own question.

Comment: There is no `PlayerNameCell_player-name-cell` class in the HTML you posted. Everything inside that div is literal text, not HTML markup. `&lt;` and `&gt;` are how `<` and `>` are encoded so they show in the output rather than being interpreted as markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the encoded HTML inside the DIV to get the elements you're looking for. You can use `html.unescape()` for this.

```
import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('my_file.html') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html")
p = soup.find('p', class_='p1')
p_parsed = html.unescape(p.text)
p_soup = BeautifulSoup(p_parsed, "html")
elements = p_soup.find_all('div', class_="PlayerNameCell_player-name-cell")
```

Also, `class` only needs to be changed to `class_` when you're using it as a named argument, not a dictionary key.

Comment: This returns an empty list for me. For what it's worth, regarding your comment on the original post, the html in the html file is encoded correctly with `<` and `>`. It is only when I open it via python they are replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Is there a way I can open my file via python with the correct encoding?

Comment: I thought what you posted was the HTML source code.

Comment: Yeah, apologies for that. I didn't realize this until just now. And to be more specific, it is `elements` that returns an empty list. `p_soup` actually does return correctly encoded html. I will do some digging to see if I can get any other classes I need to be returned.

Comment: Looks like using `class` instead of `class_` works in the `find_all`. Marking this as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. You wrote it as a dictionary rather than a named argument. `class_` is used for arguments.